# Best way to integrate Magento with an existing php application and share user database

Tags: php, magento, integration

I'm planning to connect an **existing php application** with **Magento**, in order to use it's powerful store features. I already have a database with all the user data.

What I need to do is to simplify the ordering process. Think the following scenario:

- The user first logs in into my application
- Then he goes to the products page
- User selects a product and he adds it to the cart
- Then he continue his order with Magento

What is the best way to integrate my user database with Magento? How can I make this process work without forcing the user to re-login again? How can I synchronize user data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will require to do is migrate your data to the magento database in order to do this you can have use the following options :

1. Use CSV Import / Export provided by Magento in the backend admin (where you can get your data in csv format and import it in Magento. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-product-csv-files
2. You can use Magento Core API which is meant for third part applications to connect to your system and communicate with it, but you could use it import data aswell. http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html
3. Also you can just start writing your own scripts and do this, in order to do this you will have to delve a lot more into the internal working of magento and understand the codebase.